# Pass data to javascript but got so many backslash

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm passing data from my controller to javascript.

```
public function index()
    {
        $events = Eventcalendar::get()->pluck('event');
        return view('eventcalendar.index',compact('events'));
    }
```

this is I do it in the blade

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = {!! $events !!}

  console.log(data) //the result is in the screenshot
</script>
```

how can I remove the backslash in the JSON data?

**Note: event column datatatype is JSON**

**I'm using LARAVEL 7**

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Try `json_decode($events)` in your controller function before the `return` statement

Comment: simply change `{!! $events !!}` to `@json($events)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding

```
protected $casts = [
        'event' => 'array'
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to decode your json in  controller

```
  public function index()
        {
            $events  = json_decode(Eventcalendar::get()->pluck('event'));
            return view('eventcalendar.index',compact('events'));
        }
```

Comment: Error array string convertion

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the backend code, I.E. you're sending a request to your backend, you can add `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` as a second parameter of `json_encode` function to stop escaping characters, so it should look liek this: `json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`.

If you have to handle this in Javascript, you can use `JSON.parse(string)` and iterate every entry in your array.

You might use somethig like this; initialize a new array `newData` and push the parsed data into it:

```
var newData = []
data.forEach(element => {
  newData.push(JSON.parse(element))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade)

**Rendering JSON**

> Sometimes you may pass an array to your view with the intention of
>   rendering it as JSON in order to initialize a JavaScript variable. For
>   example:

```
<script>
    var events = <?php echo json_encode($events); ?>;
</script>
```

> However, instead of manually calling json_encode, you may use the
>   @json Blade directive. The @json directive accepts the same arguments
>   as PHP's json_encode function:

```
<script>
    var events = @json($events);

    var events = @json($events, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
</script>
```